# how to make image input into 2 tables at once using Codeigniter3

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I made the data input form and the image input here the image will enter into 2 tables at once t_attch to put the image and the id increments, t_berita in the image column will fill in from id_attch which is incremented in t_attch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to describe your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem
by[image: t i] changing in the model Code to :-